# Execut bash script in PHP

Tags: php, bash, postgresql, debian, shell-exec

I need to execut a `bash` script which mainly contains a `pg_dump` and some log, clean,... stuff through a `PHP` file located in the `/var/www/` folder

My server is a `Debian Squeeze 6.0.6` with `PHP5` and `Apache2` recently installed.

My `index.php` folder contains the code below :

```
<?php
echo shell_exec('./backup_database');
?>
```

The script seems to work because I got the logs output in my browers but the `pg_dump` is not executed.

Obviously, if I run the script manually it works.

The script is located in the same folder as index.php and I used chmod 777 on those two files and on the parent directory.

P.S. I have poor knowledges in server configuration, try to be as specific as possible

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<?php
 exec('./backup_database');
?>
```

But i think your backup_database Needs an .sh ending so it can be executed. Then it should look like this

```
<?php
 exec('sh ./backup_database.sh');
?>
```

Or

```
<?php
 exec('./backup_database.sh');
?>
```

i'm not quite shure which of the two Solutions might work for you

Comment: The two first do anything, but the third print the last log (the pg_dump still not excecuted :() Maybe something on the configuration's wrong?